# Productivity Power Tools middle-click scrolling inexplicably disabled?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, productivity-power-tools

I was excited when I first found and installed the Productivity Power Tools extension for Visual Studio 2010. I particularly liked the line-highlighting, tab coloring, solution navigator and middle-click scrolling. Unfortunately after the first hour or so it was clear that the “quick find” was terrible (can’t copy/paste into it, what’s up with that?) so I turned it off in the settings and restarted Visual Studio.

Once VS refired I opened up my solution and middle clicked the (obnoxiously long) open document, hoping to casually drag my mouse downwards and scroll towards the bottom.

Instead, to my dismay, *nothing happened*. It appears as though my middle-click scrolling has now disappeared!

“Strange”, I thought, as I went about toggling the settings and restarting Visual Studio, hoping to kick it back into gear.

Alas, it proved to be a fruitless effort.

“I’ll just reinstall the whole darned extension then!” I muttered grumpily. Still I proceeded, determined to get my middle-click scrolling back.

VS fired back up *again* and, most surprisingly, **middle-click still did nothing!** (But naturally the offensive “slow find” was back in action.)

Unfortunately, as of yet, I have not found a reason or a solution for middle-click scrolling deciding to take a vacation. So if anyone has experienced anything similar and as any advice, I’m all ears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Open C:\users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions\Microsoft\Productivity Power Tools\10.0.20427.10\extension.vsixmanifest in the xml editor or notepad

2) In the Content tag, add the following line:

```
<MefComponent>Microsoft.PowerTools.MiddleClickScroll.dll</MefComponent>
```

The above worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same problem.

It appears that it's a known issue:  Enhanced Scrollbar and Middle-click scrolling share dependencies.  I'm sure at one time or another, I disabled the enhanced scrollbar, and doing so borked the middle-click functionality. See [this thread](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/view/Discussions/19), specifically the post by user **AltGr** entitled "Bug: Options Middle-Click <-> Enhanced Scroll Bar".

Comment: Ben - You probably saw/fixed this already, but this should be fixed in the latest release: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/